# Adobe illustrator perfect curve between two grids

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path

How would you combine a vertical grid and horizontal grid with matching width & heights with perfect curved lines?

Example:

[image: example]

I'm trying to find a method that would be salable for 100, 1000, etc grids.

Comment: I'd be interested in a solution as well. As far as I'm aware, there's no automated method to create precise curves of that nature, provided the verticals and horizontals already exist.

Comment: For now I found using the Arc tool you can snap to the points on both sides rather easily. I'm sure there could be a way to create some sort of macro with the arc tool.

Comment: The reral problem is that perfect curve lines is not a defined term so pretty much any connection could satisfy your need. Do you want your perfect curve to be a arc? Ellipsoid al arc? Superellipsoidal?  A spline and if so what tension? C2 Continious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would solve that by math:

The "perfect" curve means (for me) square based curve, so the task is to find the squares, create related to them arcs and make a blend in N of steps as need.

I've created 2 guides and 1 square between one square and guides intersection  -

[image]

Now I created an arc as shown and with pen tool elongated it to the second square.

[image]

[image]

The same operations for a larger arc -

[image]

[image]

And blended the arcs created -

[image]