# Replicating s curve lines where gap between is exactly the same and top and bottom lines match replicated curved lines. (Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, path

I am trying to create a downward sloping curve for an 'R' and repeat it downwards while maintaining the same width and gap between the lines.  So far I have only been able to get really close. When I replicate the top curve and try to align it below I can never get my desired result.  The height or width is always slightly off and the curve isn't flowing with the above curve. 
[image: logo lines]

I tried again using the pen tool and a bunch of guides to try and get as precise as possible but still ended up with this:
[image: second try]

I found [Adobe illustrator perfect curve between two grids](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38119/adobe-illustrator-perfect-curve-between-two-grids) and replicated it in several ways but they are 90 arcs and I want a sound shape that has a more gentle flow to it like the first picture linked.

I also want to be able to match the gaps between each line.  I was wondering how to set this up so that it would be mathematically sound; not just eyeballing it.

Answer (score 3):

Use the offset command, or effect. You can find the command in **Object → Path → Offset...**, in dialog type in width of gap and then delete the extra caps with *direct selection tool*.

[image]

**Image 1** Left to right, after offset and after deleting extra points and edges.

There are other alternatives too you can make a solid block and delete the gaps. If you make gaps with expanded strokes they are guaranteed to be equal width. Another approach is to make a art brush and stroke a brush with a gap in the middle etc etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm going to try this right now!  Thought I might add that there are a few spelling mistakes in your answer.

Comment: @ConstantFun You can edit the answers, it will then ask others if the edit is sane and if it is it gives you reputation which gives you new privileges like voting up down and so on.