# Outlining Shape Without Encroaching On Shape in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, shapes, line-art

A lot of sports logos use this effect, where shapes are outlined twice by different colors:

1. Black outline, orange outline
2. White outline, blue outline
3. Blue outline, white outline

[image]

But when I try to outline a shape in illustrator, it encroaches on that shape:

(See top image in screenshot)

What I've been doing is copying the shape, changing the color of the copy, and placing it behind the original. Then I try and and measure out both sides to make sure that there is even space and good symmetry when I resize the copy:

[image]

Is there a faster / more efficient way of doing this? Is there a way to outline the shape without the outline entering the shape and cutting off the color? Thank you.

Comment: So I am looking at this and left wondering if you have ever heard of [offset](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67507/replicating-s-curve-lines-where-gap-between-is-exactly-the-same-and-top-and-bott/)? And then my next thinking is have you heard of effects? Could you enlighten me on this for my personal interest. Seems to me this has been answered but I am unable to find a exact match. But [this post](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64362/set-a-stroke-to-knockout-a-fill-behind-it-with-live-text-in-illustrator/) is close, but using transform instead of offset.

Comment: I just learned about offset after posting, since [this](http://bit.ly/2cArWIG) link showed up as related, but I had not yet heard of transform. Both links are helpful and answer my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add multiple strokes to a single object with the Appearance panel (*Window → Appearance*). You can also use the Appearance panel on whole groups or layers. You can also apply effects to specific strokes or fills.

You can see this example is a single live text object and a single ellipse. Using the Appearance panel I added 2 strokes to the text and 3 strokes to a group containing the text and the ellipse. I also added a Transform effect to one of the strokes on the text.

[image: Appearance Panel Strokes]

Keep in mind that the order of appearance attributes matters, so in this example I had to drag "Contents" (which contains everything *in* the group) above the strokes, otherwise the strokes would be drawn on top of the groups contents.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is duplication of the object, as many times as you need. Top copies have the lesser (thinner) outlines, lower ones have the thicker outlines.