# How to create 90 degree bends with wide arc?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I've been attempting to create a graphic like the below. I've tried using the arc tool and just the path tool.

However, my results always seem wrong, for example, the spacing on the bends are uneven?

Is it a matter of trial and error with the path tool or is there a simple way in Illustrator to achieve the desired effect?

[image]

Comment: You should use offset. Anyway if you find any use for arc tool let me know, I have not found any that i couldn't do better with some other tool.  Anyway this is a duplicate of [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67507/replicating-s-curve-lines-where-gap-between-is-exactly-the-same-and-top-and-bott/67510#67510).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with a blend from two vertical lines and 6 steps:

[image: First blend]

- Menu **Object** > **Blend** > **Expand**
- Menu **Object** > **Ungroup**
- Select the lines and copy to preserve them
- Delete the central lines
- Duplicate those two lines and rotate them 90º
- Align the top and left points to create the two right angles
- Selecting each corner with the **Direct Selection Tool** > **Menu Object** > **Path** > **Join**

[image: Joining]

- Selecting the angles > Menu **Object** > **Blend** > **Make**
- Selecting the angles > Menu **Object** > **Blend** > **Blend Options** > **Specified Steps** = 6
- With the **Direct Selection Tool** select the top left anchor point and from the smooth selector, move it to the right bottom until touch the right line
- With the **Direct Selection Tool** select the top left anchor point of the small angle and from the smooth selector, move it to the right bottom
- Change the colors of each angle
- Menu **Edit** > **Paste in Place**, to recover the original blend
- Menu **Object** > **Arrange** > **Send to Back**

[image: end]

Comment: I guess the blend effect is in every AI. Maybe the rounded corner is from CC, tell me which part are you no able to do to give an option.

Answer (score 0):

There are possibly different ways to do this, but what I found that works is to create an initial curved path, then use the 'Object → Path → Offset Path' to create multiple duplicates. Select the same initial path every time and always add the same value for the 'Offset' field. So for example you offset 0.2cm the first time, then 0.4cm, then 0.6cm and so on. Add as many offsets as you need, then create the vertical lines making sure the distance between them is always 0.2cm.

Here's what I managed to produce, needs a bit of cleaning up afterwards but this will work. The initial path is shown in black.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways this could be done.

One method is to make an Art Brush

Apply it to a rounded rectangle, and delete the parts of the rectangle you don't need.

[image]